# javascript array filter from json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, filter

I need to filter some information. The information is coming from a json parse. I can't make it work. What i want is that the json is filtered into the html classes. I think I'm stupid

```
$.ajax({
    // Agenda
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'agendas',
    data: {results: 'events'},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.date, .country, .events').html('');
        $.each(response.results, function (index, result) {
            if (result.status)
                $('.date').append(result.server);
                $('.country').append(result.server);
                $('.events').append(result.server);


        });

    }
});
```

It would be lovely if someone could help me

json

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "events": {
            "id": 1,
            "date": "2022-05-06T00:00:00+00:00",
            "description": "test",
            "time": "2017-02-03T06:40:00+00:00",
            "location": "NL",
            "year": "2008",
            "event": "Idk"
        }
    },
    {
        "events": {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "2019-04-05T00:00:00+00:00",
            "description": "aasdasdasda",
            "time": "2017-02-03T15:04:00+00:00",
            "location": "asdasdasd",
            "year": "0000",
            "event": "asdasd"
        }
    }
]
}
```

css

```
  <div class="day">
                <h2 class="date">Januari 23</h2>
                <div class="country-events">
                    <span class="country">UK</span>
                    <div class="events">
                        <span class="event">Conference Amsterdam<br />11:00 CET</span>
                        <span class="event">Webinar Copenhagen<br />15:00 CET</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

UPDATE, different code same problem, I really can't get my head around this. I know it is not the correct code, I am new to json and javascript. 4th day currently so please forgive me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post sample of you json please

Comment: So why are you not appending them to the inactive div? You append everything to one list.

Comment: You just need at `if()` inside your `each` loop

Answer (score 0):

I took out the Ajax call to make it simple I added a new `ul` for inactive servers and appended new list items in.

https://jsfiddle.net/0m2xs3ah/5/

```
$.each(response.results,function(index, value){
    if(value.status){
      $('#active-servers').append('<li>'+value.server+'</li>');
  }else{
    $('#inactive-servers').append('<li>'+value.server+'</li>');
  }

});
```

```js
var response = {
"results": [
    {
        "server": "server04.republic-m.com",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "server": "server06.republic-m.com",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "server": "server06.republic-m.com",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "server": "server17.republic-m.com",
        "status": false
    },
    {
        "server": "server18.republic-m.com",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "server": "server20.republic-m.com",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "server": "server21.republic-m.com",
        "status": false
    },
    {
        "server": "server25.republic-m.com",
        "status": true
    }
]
}

$.each(response.results,function(index, value){
 if(value.status){
     $('#active-servers').append('<li>'+value.server+'</li>');
  }else{
    $('#inactive-servers').append('<li>'+value.server+'</li>');
  }

});

var servers = response.results;
var onlineServers = servers.filter(function(server){
 if(server.status){
   return (server.status == true);  
  }

});
var offlineServers = servers.filter(function(server){
 if(!server.status){
   return (server.status == false);  
  }
});

console.log(offlineServers)
console.log(onlineServers)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span>Active</span>
  <ul id= "active-servers">

  </ul>
</div>

<div>
<span>Inactive</span>
  <ul id= "inactive-servers">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only need an if statement to choose in which div put the results:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'servers',
        data: {results:'results', status:'status'},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#active-servers, #inactive-servers').html('');
            $.each(response.results,function(index,result){
                if (result.status)
                    $('#active-servers').append('<li>'+result.server+'</li>');
                else
                    $('#inactive-servers').append('<li>'+result.server+'</li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Both of those dont work, if it is FALSE the inactive servers should be shown with the servers that are inactive in there, if its TRUE the active servers should be shown in the active servers

Comment: @DamianAshworth I've updated my answer and I think now it should be ok. Anyway, if you debug in Chrome, you will find yourself where is the mistake

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it a lot.

Kind Regards,

Damian